# Why some SE sites measure impact and others like Electrical Engineering don't?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm seeing two types of SE websites. I noticed that some SE sites measure "impact" in the activity tab such as Stack Overflow, Mathematics, while others such as Electrical Engineering, Physics don't have this feature. What is the reason? Why don't all SE sites measure impact, why aren't they all the same?

Comment: SE crew is gradually updating stacks one-by-one with new user profile designs.  Work in progress.

Comment: Ah, so it is a feature to be implemented. Ok.